# Laravel 5.5: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

Because my database had an error and didn't start anymore I reinstalled mysql completely. But now my laravel project is broken.
**Errors:**
*When I visit the site:*

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'asp.projects' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `projects`)
```

*When I run console commands:*

```
In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'asp.projects' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `projects`)


In Connection.php line 326:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'asp.projects' doesn't exist
```

I already tried:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan migrate:reset
php artisan dump-autoload
composer dump-autoload
```

Sadly I am not quite sure what I should do. All of these commands will return the error.
I am sorry when the answer has been already posted here but I couldn't find it.
I hope you can help me,
Tom

Comment: Have you checked your models ,whether projects table model exist

Comment: Schema::table is to modify an existing table, use Schema::create to create new. ;) check this also in your migration

Comment: Check your migrations to make sure that all of the table creations are there.

Comment: Did you create the database itself? `create database asp`

Comment: thanks for your answers :) I found out what I did wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My fault was that I had the variable `$project = App\Project::all()` defined in `routes\web.php`
When I had the migration this worked well but as soon as I had to migrate again it caused the error.